# how to hide background when image is zoomed in

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a tap gesture recognizer hooked up to my image view. When the image is tapped it becomes full screen and when tapped again it is dismissed. The user has the ability to pinch to zoom the image, however when the image is held down and moved around by the user it shows the background view. I want to hide the background so the view can not be seen until the image is dismissed. I think the images I have provided will explain better than I can through words.

```
var newImageView: UIImageView!



@IBAction func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)


    newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0

    scrollView.addSubview(newImageView)

    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
{
    return newImageView;
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

[image: regular view]

[image]
[image]

Comment: take a view under the imageview with full screen and also show and hide that view same as image view also give that view Black or any color you want

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide an element with the `backgroundElement.isHidden = true` property. You can reset the background using `backgroundElement.isHidden = false` once the view has been dismissed.

Comment: which element should isHidden be called on, I tried to call it on "view.isHidden= true" but that was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Use following method of UIScrollView to check at what Scale it is zoomed.

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    print(scale)
    if scale == 1.0 {
        self.lblDesc.isHidden = false
        self.btnDelete.isHidden = false
    } else {

    }
}
```

When scale is 1.0 it is normal minimumZoomScale.

Following is method called when you zoom. Use it to hide your elements.

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lblDesc.isHidden = true
    self.btnDelete.isHidden = true
}
```

Hope it helps you.